# Using ifstream to read .txt file with comma

Tags: c++, string, stream, ifstream

Based on ifstream I am using the following function to read filename.txt file

```cpp
//reading from text file
static std::vector<double> vec;
double a[18]; //values got read from txt file
int i = 0;
void readDATA()
{
    double value;
    std::ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open("filename.txt", std::ios::app);
    if (myFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "File is open." << std::endl;
        while (myFile >> value)
        {
            vec.push_back(value);
            std::cout << "value is " << value << std::endl;
            a[i] = value;
            std::cout << "a" << i << "=" << a[i] << std::endl;
            i = i + 1;
        }
        myFile.close();
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Unable to open the file";
}
```

it works correctly
Below is the content of filename.txt file:

```
0 0 40 45 15
0 1 40 -45 10
0 0 180 90 15
```

Could you please help me in **modifying the function** such that I can read the same .txt file with **comma separation** between the elements?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to read number followed optionally by colon?

Define class that will handle this "task":

```
struct Number 
{
   double value;
   operator double() const { return value; }
}; 
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, Number& number)
{
     is >> number.value;
     // fail istream on anything other than ',' or whitespace
     // end reading on ',' or '\n'
    for (char c = is.get();; c = is.get()) {
        if (c == ',' or c == '\n')
            break;
        if (std::isspace(c))
            continue;

        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        break;
    }
     return is;
}
```

Then in your code - replace `double value;` with `Number value;`

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2CZNLuHOfXGAfOGY)

Comment: I want to read number followed by comma from the txt file

Comment: 0, 0, 40, 45, 15 \n
0, 1, 40, -45, 10 \n
0, 0, 180, 90, 15 \n

Comment: @Iko-SOF - I wrote the code w/o compiling, running or verifying it. Now it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the demo. Actually, what I mean by \n is new line. To be more clear plz find in the link the txt file which I am trying to read https://filebin.net/18fqrqlx6421o5vv  It's important to me to modify the code which I already provided in the question to let it read the file uploaded in the link

Comment: Everything is in my answer. Add the code I provided - and  "Then in your code - replace double value; with Number value;"

Comment: Two things to clarify from your comments. ifstream is a istream. So, if I wrote function for istream - it will work for ifstream as well. And, yes I know you mean \n - \n in strings mean the same as in txt file. Once again use my code in yours.

Comment: Could you please help me in other two things: First- having the ability to assign manual value to a[i] if i was not available in the .txt file (e.g. first line in text file is 0, 0, 40, , 15  the forth element in nothing and in this case I want to assign it manually in the code to be for instance 70). Second- letting the code read not only numbers but also strings (dealing with numbers and strings for example 0,0,8,"turn_right",4)

Comment: If you have another problem - ask another question. On SO comments section cannbot be too long or replace Q/A. You might refer to this Q in your new Q. And - if you found this my answer resolwing your current problem - you can accept/upvote.

Comment: Thanks, I will refer it in a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65275129/using-ifstream-to-assign-default-value-if-it-was-not-declared-in-txt-file

Comment: could you please take a look at this question it's a continue to this one @PiotrNycz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65645056/how-to-read-n-values-from-txt-file-using-c

Answer (score 0):

something like this you can try

```
std::string data;
while(std::getline(myFile, data)) {
    std::istringstream ss(data);
    std::string token;

    while(std::getline(ss, token, ','))
        double d = std::stod(token);
}
```